# Not all image metadata retrieved by CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex

Tags: swift, image, metadata

I am trying to retrieve all metadata from an iPhone 8 album image in iOS from a Swift project in Xcode 13 using the following code:

```
if let image = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage {
        let url  = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL.rawValue]
        let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as! CFURL, nil)
        let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source!,0,nil) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
```

However, if I print out metadata, no GPS or Camera metadata is shown, and some fields of the EXIF data. The output is as below. How can I access all of the image metadata?

```
    (lldb) po metadata
▿ Optional<Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>>
  ▿ some : 10 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("Orientation")
        - value : "Orientation"
      - value : 1
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("DPIWidth")
        - value : "DPIWidth"
      - value : 72
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("PixelWidth")
        - value : "PixelWidth"
      - value : 4032
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("ColorModel")
        - value : "ColorModel"
      - value : RGB
    ▿ 4 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("Depth")
        - value : "Depth"
      - value : 8
    ▿ 5 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("{Exif}")
        - value : "{Exif}"
      ▿ value : 7 elements
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          - key : ColorSpace
          - value : 1
        ▿ 1 : 2 elements
          - key : PixelXDimension
          - value : 4032
        ▿ 2 : 2 elements
          - key : ExifVersion
          ▿ value : 3 elements
            - 0 : 2
            - 1 : 2
            - 2 : 1
        ▿ 3 : 2 elements
          - key : FlashPixVersion
          ▿ value : 2 elements
            - 0 : 1
            - 1 : 0
        ▿ 4 : 2 elements
          - key : PixelYDimension
          - value : 3024
        ▿ 5 : 2 elements
          - key : SceneCaptureType
          - value : 0
        ▿ 6 : 2 elements
          - key : ComponentsConfiguration
          ▿ value : 4 elements
            - 0 : 1
            - 1 : 2
            - 2 : 3
            - 3 : 0
    ▿ 6 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("PixelHeight")
        - value : "PixelHeight"
      - value : 3024
    ▿ 7 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("{TIFF}")
        - value : "{TIFF}"
      ▿ value : 4 elements
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          - key : Orientation
          - value : 1
        ▿ 1 : 2 elements
          - key : ResolutionUnit
          - value : 2
        ▿ 2 : 2 elements
          - key : XResolution
          - value : 72
        ▿ 3 : 2 elements
          - key : YResolution
          - value : 72
    ▿ 8 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("DPIHeight")
        - value : "DPIHeight"
      - value : 72
    ▿ 9 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("ProfileName")
        - value : "ProfileName"
      - value : Display P3

(lldb)
```

Comment: You can get the location from the PHAsset.

Comment: How can I access all the other metadata (Camera etc)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for iOS 13 or later as below using PHAsset. The problem is the way data is created.

```
let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)
    
    let image = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage
    
    let asset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset.rawValue] as! PHAsset
    
    PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: asset, options: nil) { (data, responseString, imageOrient, info) in
        let imageData: NSData = data! as NSData
        let source3:CGImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
        let metadata3 = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source3,0, nil) as? [AnyHashable: Any]

       //use metadata3 which contains all metadata for jpeg files but executed asynchronously

       }
```